# Invoking JavaScript code without failing builds on mobile

Tags: javascript, flutter

I need to call a JS function from a flutter widget on flutter web.

I know I can use the code below, but the problem is that it fails the build on mobile, because flutter does not offer anyway to conditionally import a file.

Any solution to prevent me from having to comment out lines of code when building for mobile?

```
import 'dart:js';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        // Call a JavaScript function with two arguments
        context.callMethod('myFunction', ['arg1', 'arg2']);

        // Call a JavaScript function that returns a value
        var result = context.callMethod('myFunction2');
        print(result);
      },
      child: Text('Invoke JavaScript'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read the guide on [formatting](/help/formatting). Using all caps is considered shouting on the internet, there's no need for that. Also, bold+italic formatting just makes things hard to read, as opposed to what you think it does. It doesn't make it clearer, nor stand out. As a kind of summary it isn't necessary either, given you only have three sentences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kIsWeb` to know that you have web or not, something like this:

```
import 'dart:js';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        if(kIsWeb){
        // Call a JavaScript function with two arguments
        context.callMethod('myFunction', ['arg1', 'arg2']);

        // Call a JavaScript function that returns a value
        var result = context.callMethod('myFunction2');
        print(result);
      }
     else{
      // this is for mobile or others
     }
      },
      child: Text('Invoke JavaScript'),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;
import 'dart:io' as io;
if(kIsWeb){
{
     return WebPage();  //your web page with web package import in it
}
else if(!kIsWeb && io.Platform.isAndroid) {
     return AndroidPage();  //your android page with android package import in it
    } 
//you can add others condition...
```

Comment: the first line "import 'dart:js';" will automatically fail the mobile build

Comment: hey bro, I've Edited the answer please see that does the roadmap that I showed working for you or not.